# Visual Studio 2015, SDL2 LNK2019: unresolved external

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unresolved-external

I'm trying to start using SDL2 but when I compile I get these errors:

```
1>SDL2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__fprintf referenced in function _ShowError
1>SDL2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp____iob_func referenced in function _ShowError
1>E:\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\SDL2_Test\Debug\SDL2_Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

I have have just upgraded from vs2010 to vs2015.

Everything is linked up correctly.
Here's the source code if it's to any help.

```
#include "SDL.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    return 0;
}
```

Im guessing there's something wrong with "SDL2main.lib", but I have no idea how to fix it.

That's all, thanks.

Comment: Does it still appear if you comment out `#include "SDL.h"`? You need to link the SDL library obviously.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, nope. All the libraries are linked already. Clearly the compiler is correctly linked because it can open the SDL2main.lib.